# Multiple WHERE clauses in sqlite3 python

Tags: python, sqlite, where-clause

How do you add multiple WHERE clauses in an sqlite3 query, for example:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE driverID=? AND WHERE accepted='False'", (str(sid_login.get()),))
```

Although I get 'near "WHERE": syntax error' error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just use one `WHERE` and combine conditions with `AND`:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE driverID=? AND accepted=?",
          (sid_login.get(), False))
```

Also, instead of manually quoting `False`, you could use parametrization and let sqlite3 do it for you.